# XPath find attributes with specific values

Tags: xpath

I am sure this should be easier than I'm making it but I'm trying to get the following response from my source.  Please could somebody help me with the xpath?

I am trying to select the line elements with the values "extract".   In real world, I'm reading a text file and using xml and want to pick out the lines which read extract.

Source

```
<line>
<line number="1">blah</line>
<line number="2">extract</line>
<line number="3">blah</line>
<line number="4">extract</line>
</line>
```

Required Response:

```
<line>
<line number="2">extract</line>
<line number="4">extract</line>
</line>
```

or even just

extract

extract

would be fine.

Many Thanks,

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two short solutions. :)

Comment: Yes, this is simple. But it needs some clarification. If you want a transformation (an XML result) then you need XSLT. If you want to **select** the text nodes **containing** the string "extract", then this is posible with just XPath. If you want to select the text nodes with "extract" string value, that looks odd as a requeriment...

Answer (score 1):

This (use `=` if you use XPath 1.0):

```
/line/line[text() eq 'extract']/text()
```

will give you: ([See evaluation](http://xmltools.dk/VQArALAA))

```
extract
extract
```

The reason why `//line` is not a good idea, is that you use `line` tags for 2 things (your top tag `line` and your childs of `line`) - you should not do that :-/. If you want the elements instead of the text, you can write:

```
/line/line[text() eq 'extract']
```

And last, this will give you the count (it seems it is what you really need?)

```
count(/line/line[text() eq 'extract'])
```

Comment: @lasseespeholt: `eq` is an XPath 2.0 operator.

Comment: @lasseespeholt: Besides I agree with you about the recomendation to not use starting `//` operator, the deleted solution `//line[contains(text(),'extract')]` **will work**, because `line` root element doesn't have a text node **child** containing "extract" string. Other case it would be if you use string value (with current `.` implicit casting, or with `string()` function).

Comment: I don't know whether you are correct, but XQSharp (try "See evaluation") says it doesn't work but it could be implemented wrong. It is because `text()` is not one string. Furthermore, `contains` could trigger at wrong values ex `contains(.., 'a')` will be true with `blah`.

Comment: @Alejandro Thanks for the XPath 2.0 comment by the way :)

Comment: @lasseespeholt: That is why it's important to make distintions between XPath 1.0 and 2.0. The later has less and different rules for implicit casting, so you needs `//line[contains(text()[1],'extract')]` (the right `item()` argument for implicit `string()` function call).

Comment: @Alejandro Thanks for enlightened me :) I guess the whole thing is now depending on whether he use XPath 1.0 or XPath 2.0 and whether he wants contains or equals :)

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
/*/*[.='extract']/text()
```

**or even**:

```
//text()[.='extract']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//line[contains(text(), 'extract')]
```

EDIT: This works for XPath 1.0, and it obviously searches for the string (rather than requiring equality).

Comment: This will fail, because in this case `//line` is not equal to `/line/line` and the top tag `line` contains multiple strings so `contains` fail. And `contains()` might trigger at wrong values ex `contains(text(), 'a')` will give you all items.

Answer (score 0):

Since your subject mentions attributes (even if your question doesn't) I assume you want to find the value of the `number` attribute for all matching lines. If so:

```
/line/line[text()='extract']/@number
```